# Using Laravel + Redis + Node.js on Heroku for websocket app... worried about connection limit

Tags: node.js, laravel, heroku, websocket, redis

This is a bit of a stretch, but I hope someone can help.

I'm a PHP/iOS developer who's been working on an app that has a messaging component. Front end is Obj-C, backend is PHP/MySQL currently. As I've gone further into development, I'm feeling the shortcomings of polling and I've been looking for a more realtime solution and, sure enough, I've found the answer in web sockets. PHP doesn't play too well in this domain, but I've been able to get things working locally by using Laravel + Redis + Node.js.

Next I needed to find a suitable host for the real world app deployment and this is where I'm running into my first major obstacle (or perceived obstacle?)

Heroku appears to have very low limits on the number of Redis connections allowable:

Link: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis
Free plan: 20 connections
$120/month: 400 connections
$1450/month: 5000 connections

The problem is, if this app does well and gains the kind of traction I want, a LOT of people will be using it at the same time all across the country and these limits have me worried. These prices seem a bit ridiculous or I'm not looking at it correctly.

So my question is, does maintaining an open web socket (one user) mean that one of the Redis connections is used? Or am I looking at this completely wrong? Trying to decide if I need to just stick to polling or if there is a cost-efficient solution to this. I do want to stick to Laravel/Redis if possible because I am not too familiar with JS and I feel that my backend will be much less secure if I try to go down that route at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper design will use 2 Redis connections per server (or per Heroku Dyno):

One connection will be used to Subscribe (to listen) to the app's channel(s). This connection cannot be used for other functions, so...

A second connection is used for all other Redis features, such as Database use and Publishing to the app's channel(s).

I don't know if you're into Ruby, but I'm the author of the [Plezi Http(REST)/Websocket framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) and had to manage a solution for Plezi's scaling capabilities over Redis (which is an automated feature, you just tell Plezi the Redis server's address and you're good to go).

If you want to look over [Plezi's Redis code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/fcbfb82f6b08c70629fd00a97d77e159b09d11c5/lib/plezi/common/redis.rb), you will notice there are two connections and that each server registers to two channels - a global channel and a private channel: one used for application wide events and the other one allows messages to be routed to specific connections based on the server they belong to (avoiding workload on unrelated servers).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!  I will definitely have to look into this, I appreciate the clarity in your answer.